# in node.js, if using createReadStream() do you still need response.end()

Tags: javascript, node.js

[node.js doc](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) says

#### response.end([data], [encoding])

> This method signals to the server that all of the response headers and body have been sent; that server should consider this message complete. The method, response.end(), MUST be called on each response.

but in the many examples given using using `createReadStream`, eg,

```
 fs.createReadStream(filename,{...}).pipe(response)
```

I never see `response.end()` called.

it `resonse.end()` needed with `createReadStream()`?  and, if so, where does it appear in the program flow - you don't want it called until the pipe is finished, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do `response.end()` after reading is finished (`end` event) or you encounter an error (`error` event).

Check this example: http://elegantcode.com/2011/04/06/taking-baby-steps-with-node-js-pumping-data-between-streams/

Comment: thanks, saw that.  look in third example where they're actually piping: they are _not_ using `response.end()`.  perhaps `util.pump()` or `.pipe(response)` call `response.end()`, but see nothing of that in the docs.

Comment: check [here](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipe_destination_options) `By default end() is called on the destination when the source stream emits end`